# Use C# to gather event logs from a specified time period

Tags: c#, wmi, event-log

Does anybody know if its possible to save the windows event logs from a given time interval as a text file with C#? For example say I want to save the System event logs from between 10 - 11 am in a text file. If it is possible does anybody have a link to a good tutorial or maybe a code snippet that could get me going? I have searched online but cant get what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/93268-working-with-the-system-event-log-with-c%23-intro/

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Just adding info for others on how to filter event logs by time range as part of the WMI query.

Note that 'TimeGenerated' is when events happen and 'TimeWritten' when they are logged.
The 'RecordNumber' is a unique index, useful for preventing collision or duplicate logging.

There is **System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter** that converts between C# DateTime and the WMI CIM_DATETIME format.
But be aware it makes the UTC CIM into a LOCAL DateTime while leaving Kind Unspecified, so set Kind afterwards to avoid headaches!

This is an example for grabbing security failures ( to track lockouts ) in the last 30 minutes:

```
private void SearchEventViewer(string computerName, string userName, string userPass)
{
    var scope = CreateManagementScope(computerName, userName, userPass);
    var startTime = ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDmtfDateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-30));
    var query = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE Logfile = 'Security' AND EventType = '5' AND TimeGenerated > '" + startTime + "'");

    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query))
    {
        var result = searcher.Get();

        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            var eventTimeLocal = DateTime.SpecifyKind(ManagementDateTimeConverter.ToDateTime(item["TimeGenerated"].ToString()), DateTimeKind.Local);
            var eventTimeUtc   = eventTimeLocal.ToUniversalTime();

            var eventDetails = item["Message"].ToString().Replace("\r\n\r\n", "\r\n");
            eventDetails += "\r\nEventCode: "     + item["EventCode"];
            eventDetails += "\r\nCatogory: "      + item["Category"];
            eventDetails += "\r\nRecord Number: " + item["RecordNumber"];
            eventDetails += "\r\nLocal Time: "    + eventTimeLocal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

            // Do something...
        }
    }
}

private ManagementScope CreateManagementScope(string computerName, string username = "", string password = "")
{
    var managementPath = @"\\" + computerName + @"\root\cimv2";
    var scope = new ManagementScope(managementPath);

    if (username != "" && password != "")
    {
        scope.Options = new ConnectionOptions
        {
            Username = username,
            Password = password,
            Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
            Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
        };
    }

    return scope;
}
```